# Most frequent occurance size per user

Tags: r

Unfortunately I have another problem I´m not able to solve alone - I want to list the size the every user ordered the most. When 2 or more sizes have the same occurency it should write an "-"

Tried it already with data table but I´m stuck on how to solve it ;)

```
setDT(DB)[, `:=` (mostorderedsize = .N), by='customerID,size']
```

Expected outcome:

```
mostorderedsize = c("m", "-", 42, "m", "m", 42, "-", "-", "m", "m")
```

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","2.1.14", "2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
size = c("m", "l", 42, "xxl", "m", 42, 39, "m", "xl", 44),
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
ItemReturned = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Hope you're able to show me what´s wrong or show me another possibility to solve the problem.

Comment: You say you want the size every user ordered the most. I only count 3 customer ID's yet your expected result shows 10 sizes. Do you want the result merged back in?

Comment: yes- it´s always "m" for user 1; "-" for user 2 and "42" for user 3: and the most ordered size should be written in every line of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Base R:

Using `tapply` to loop over the customerID groups and summarize the sizes using `table`

```
tmp <- with(DB, tapply(size, customerID, function(x) {
  tbl <- table(x)
  most <- which(tbl == max(tbl))
  if (length(most) > 1) return('-') else return(names(tbl)[most])
}))
```

Then can index with the customerID column to broadcast the result:

```
DB$mostoreredsize <- tmp[DB$customerID]
DB
> DB
   orderID orderDate itemID size customerID ItemReturned mostoreredsize
1        1    1.1.14      2    m          1            0              m
2        2    1.1.14      3    l          2            0              -
3        3    1.1.14      2   42          3            0             42
4        4    1.1.14      5  xxl          1            1              m
5        5    2.1.14     12    m          1            1              m
6        6    2.1.14      4   42          3            0             42
7        7    2.1.14      2   39          2            1              -
8        8    2.1.14      3    m          2            0              -
9        9    2.1.14      1   xl          1            0              m
10      10    2.1.14      5   44          1            0              m
```

Comment: tmp is properly working but I have problems with the 2. part- it´s not working: DB$mostoreredsize <- tmp[DB$customerID]

Comment: What is the error? Is `customerID` an integer, numeric, factor...?

Comment: customerID=integer, size=factor; no error-the whole column is NA

Comment: When I run the `data.frame` you have listed in your question with the code I provided in my answer, I see the correct output. If you do `class(DB)` and `class(tmp)`, what are the results? Are you working with a `data.table` instead?

Comment: found what´s wrong: customerId needs to be a factor (don´t know why, but now it´s working...) thanks for your help buddy!